# iOS: Firebase removeValue seems to be corrupting array data?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

So I've been running into a bizarre problem. Essentially, I have an array which is the data source for a tableView:

```
data : [(String: SomeDataStruct)] = [(username1, data1), (username2, data2), (username3, data3)...]
```

In my firebase database, my data is:

[image]

If I delete a value from the tableview, this is done by deleting the corresponding item from the array. I then delete the item from firebase to keep the data in sync. For example if I want to delete username2, I remove the tuple with username2 from the array - it's at index 1. Then I use:

```
data : [(String: SomeDataStruct)] = [(username1, data1), (username2, data2), (username3, data3)...]

referenceToOrders.child("username2").removeValue(completionBlock: { (err, ref) in

    print(data)
    // data is [] when it should be [(username1, data1), (username3, data3), (username4 ... ]

})
```

I've isolated it down to this one line - for some reason invoking the firebase removeValue function results in the data array getting wiped out. As a workaround, before invoking the call, I create a copy of the data array. However, I'm not happy with this solution.

Help?

Comment: Your Firebase call shouldn't be the cause of the removal of your "stored local array". Show us how you're removing an element from your tuple array.

Comment: What is `data`? A local array? You should check the `Firebase` db after removing the child and see if it exists of removed. You will get to know the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering for future reference and others.

So after adding a lot of print statements, I found out that the issue was that I had a observe Firebase handler that ran right after the removeValue but before the completion handler. Makes sense because the database has changed at this point, so the handler fires.